# Obtain specific sections of a text file and their contents

Tags: r

I have a text file that looks like:

```
1 Hello
1.1 Hi
1.2 Hey
2 Next section
2.1 New section
3 thrid
4 last
```

I have another text file that looks like.

```
1 Hello
My name is John. It was nice to meet you.
1.1 Hi
Hi again. My last name is Doe.
1.1.1 Bye
1.2 Hey
Greetings.
2 Next section
This is the second section. I am majoring in CS.
2.1 New Section
Welcome. I am an undergraduate student.
3 third
1. hi
2. hello
3. hey
4 last
```

I was wondering how you could read in data from the previous text file, and use it to find the specific sections within the second data file and all the content after it uptil the the next section. So basically, I'm trying to get something like:

```
Section      Content
1 Hello      My name is John. It was nice to meet you.
1.1 Hi       Hi again. My last name is Doe. 1.1.1 Bye
1.2 Hey      Greetings.
```

.....And so on

I was wondering how I could do so.

Comment: Could your input be a subsection too? In which case what would your output be? Till the next subsection or till the next section?

Comment: If the input is a subsection, then the output woud be till the next subsection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution might certainly be improved, but it might provide you with an idea how to approach your issue. Depending on the size and structure of the files you need to process, this approach might be ok or require more tuning concerning the detection of sections and the speed.

```
file1 = 
"1 Hello
1.1 Hi
1.2 Hey
2 Next section
2.1 New section
3 thrid
4 last"

file2 = 
"1 Hello
My name is John. It was nice to meet you.
1.1 Hi
Hi again. My last name is Doe.
1.1.1 Bye
1.2 Hey
Greetings.
2 Next section
This is the second section. I am majoring in CS.
2.1 New Section
Welcome. I am an undergraduate student.
3 third
1. hi
2. hello
3. hey
4 last"

file1 = unlist(strsplit(file1, "\n", fixed = T))
file2 = unlist(strsplit(file2, "\n", fixed = T))
positions = unlist(sapply(file1, function(x) grep(paste0("^", x, "$"), file2, ignore.case = T)))
positions = cbind(positions, c(positions[-1]-1, length(file2)))
text = mapply(function(x, y) file2[x:y], positions[,1], positions[,2])             
text = lapply(text, function(x) x[-1])
result = cbind(positions, text)
result
# positions    text                                              
# 1 Hello         1         2  "My name is John. It was nice to meet you."       
# 1.1 Hi          3         5  Character,2                                       
# 1.2 Hey         6         7  "Greetings."                                      
# 2 Next section  8         9  "This is the second section. I am majoring in CS."
# 2.1 New section 10        15 Character,5                                       
# 4 last          16        16 Character,0  

# Note that the text column contains lists storing the individual lines.
# e.g. for "2.1 New section":
class(result[5, "text"])
# list
result[5, "text"]
# [[1]]
# [1] "Welcome. I am an undergraduate student." "3 third"  #<< note the different spelling of third                              
# [3] "1. hi"                                   "2. hello"                               
# [5] "3. hey"
```

Comment: Why does 1.1 Hi, and 2.1 New Section, and 4 last show up as Character, #. Do you know what could be the difference between those sections and the others?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The results in the text column are stored as lists. If the list contains more than one element only its lenght and its the type of its elements is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I accepted your answer. I just had one more question. The strings from my text file. The product of readLines(textfile) does not work well as an input for file1 and file2. readFile does not work either well as inputs for the files. Is there a better way to extract text from a text file to a string object, exactly in the same format and spacing, as it is in the text file.

Comment: Alright, thanks for accepting. What is the output of readLines applied on your files? You might update your answer with the output. It might also suffice to only post the output of the shorter file as example, sonce I guess that the files have the same structure in general.

Comment: Ya, I guess larger files are probably more difficult to handle. Thanks though!

Comment: And is there a way to get all of the "Character,#" lists to show up as strings at the same time, so its easier to read through.

Comment: Concerning reading larger textfiles you might try `fread`from `data.table` its quite fast. `readLines` is slower but works better from my experience if your files contain non standard characters, etc. - so it depends on your files. Furthermore, you might go multicore, e.g., via `text2vec` and [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/files-multicore.html).

Comment: Concerning better readability you might add an additional column that only inlcudes the first element of the list (which is then printed visibly), in a way like `lapply(result[, "text"], function(x) x[1])`. If you want longer strings you might extract the first X elements and paste them together via `paste0(..., collapse = "")`. However, there is a certain limit of characters printed per line, never tried this, so I am not sure how many will actually show up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is Yes, it can be done.  The implementation will vary wildly based on what programming language that you are using to accomplish this task.  High level overview would be

1. split original file into string array by line.  These are you list of keys for searching the second document.
2. read second file into string variable
3. iterate through all your keys (iterator x) and find their index in the second document.  something like

> int start = seconddocument.indexof(keys[x]);
>   int end = seconddocument.indexof(keys[x+1]);

4. then with these start and end positions you can use a substring() function to extract the content.

> string matchedContent = seconddocument.substring(start, end);

This works until you get to the last match because keys[x+1] will not exist where x is the last key.  in this case end needs to be set to the position of the last character in the document, or you use a substring method that just takes a starting point.

HTH